# PhpStorm does not recognize CodeIgniter v3.0 database method in class

Tags: codeigniter, phpstorm

While there are many answers on how to get PhpStorm to recognize the CodeIgniter 2.x core functions, I can not figure out how to get it to recognize the CodeIgniter **3.0** database functions.

I have an `autocomplete.php` file in my config directory that works great for CodeIgniter 2.x (and most of v3.0). Since v3 removed the active record class, the DB functions are no longer recognized.

```
 // help IDE(s) support Codeigniter 2.0
  * @property CI_DB_active_record $db  <-- no longer valid.
  ...
 */
```

How can I get PhpStorm autocomplete working with the new CI v3 DB class?

Update: Here is my autocomplete.php file:

```
<?php
// help IDE(s) support Codeigniter 2.0
/**
 * @property CI_DB_query_builder $db
 * @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
 * @property CI_Benchmark $benchmark
 * @property CI_Calendar $calendar
 * @property CI_Cart $cart
 * @property CI_Config $config
 * @property CI_Controller $controller
 * @property CI_Email $email
 * @property CI_Encrypt $encrypt
 * @property CI_Exceptions $exceptions
 * @property CI_Form_validation $form_validation
 * @property CI_Ftp $ftp
 * @property CI_Hooks $hooks
 * @property CI_Image_lib $image_lib
 * @property CI_Input $input
 * @property CI_Language $language
 * @property CI_Loader $load
 * @property CI_Log $log
 * @property CI_Model $model
 * @property CI_Output $output
 * @property CI_Pagination $pagination
 * @property CI_Parser $parser
 * @property CI_Profiler $profiler
 * @property CI_Router $router
 * @property CI_Session $session
 * @property CI_Sha1 $sha1
 * @property CI_Table $table
 * @property CI_Trackback $trackback
 * @property CI_Typography $typography
 * @property CI_Unit_test $unit_test
 * @property CI_Upload $upload
 * @property CI_URI $uri
 * @property CI_User_agent $user_agent
 * @property CI_Validation $validation
 * @property CI_Xmlrpc $xmlrpc
 * @property CI_Xmlrpcs $xmlrpcs
 * @property CI_Zip $zip
 *
 *
 *
 * These are samples entries to make my own functions work. Remove these and add you custom ones.

 * @property Tank_auth $tank_auth
 * @property Users_model $users_model
 * @property Firms_model $firms_model
 * @property Event_types_model $event_types_model
 * @property Files_model $files_model
 * @property Milestones_model $milestones_model
 *
 *
 */
class CI_Controller {}; class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {}; class Welcome extends MY_Controller {}; class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {}; class CI_Model {}; class MY_Model extends CI_Model {};/**
 * @property CI_DB_query_builder $db
 * @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
 * @property CI_Config $config
 * @property CI_Loader $load
 * @property CI_Session $session
 */
// class CI_Model {};
/* End of file autocomplete.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/autocomplete.php */
```

In a controller, $this->db->where(); is recognized and a command click takes me to the source of that function. However, $query->num_rows() gives a "Cannot find a declaration to go to" error when clicked.

In a Model, none of the CI DB functions are recognized.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download gist file from https://gist.github.com/topdown/1697338
2. Put it in the root of your CodeIgniter project (where the `index.php` is).
3. In PhpStorm's Project View panel, go to (expand) `system/core/`
4. Right click on `Controller.php` and choose `Mark as Plain Text`
5. Do the same for `Model.php`

I am using PhpStorm 9 may this help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but please read the question closely. This is a problem with CI v3.0. The file you link to is for CI 2.x. Active Record class is gone in 3.0

Comment: @TimDuncklee it's still possible by If you're using CI 3 you maybe have to change some class names.
**but you can also add class declarations in this file as well, so after your property comments as above put stuff like this:**

`class CI_Controller {};
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {};
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {};
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {};
class CI_Model {};
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {}; `

I have configured it onmy friends system using CI-3 and phpstorm try this will definetly work

Comment: I believe my problem is that I can not figure out what exactly to replace this with: * @property CI_DB_active_record $db now that active record is gone. I did try your suggestion and no go. Sorry...

Comment: @TimDuncklee you have replace DB.php in system folder and look for another files that are changed in CI-3

Comment: Humm... I don't think it's wise to be replacing system files. Even IF I wanted to do that, I have no idea what to replace it with...

Comment: no i am suggesting to replace  @ property CI_DB_active_record $db with @ DB_query_builder.php and so on

Comment: AH! I did try that and no luck. I was hoping someone who had done it could give me the actual code.  * @property CI_DB_query_builder $db is the first one I tried.

Comment: @TimDuncklee can you exactly post the code what have you done so far i need to solve this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to do with the following steps:-

1. Create and put phpstorm.php file in the root of your CodeIgniter project.
2. In PhpStorm’s Project View panel, go to (expand)  system/core/.
3. Right click on Controller.php and choose Mark as Plain Text.
4. Do the same for Model.php for the model navigation .